# Regexp и golang

Tags: регулярные-выражения, golang

Всем привет.

Столкнулся с неприятной проблемой:
В проекте оказалось необходимо хранить некоторое количество настроек в внешнем файле, я выбрал json так как поддержка такого формата есть из коробки. И всё шло хорошо, но до тех пор, пока в этих настройках не понадобилось хранить и периодически менять регулярное выражение.
Теперь при попытках получить значения переменных из json'ов выдаёт ошибку "invalid character '.' in string escape code".

Код чтения json ниже:

```
func GetSettings() settings {
    file, err := os.Open("conf/settings.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(file)
    settings := settings{}
    err = decoder.Decode(&settings)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    return settings
}
```

Само выражение:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9\.\_\-\']{2,128})(@iccmiu\.online)$
```

JSON такого вида:

```
{
   "Emails": [
     {
       "Type": "iccmiu",
       "Regexp": "^([a-zA-Z0-9\.\_\-\']{2,128})(@iccmiu\.online)$"
     }
     {
       "Type": "gohryt",
       "Regexp": "^([a-zA-Z0-9\.\_\-\']{2,128})(@gohryt\.online)$"
     }
 ]
}
```

Comment: кавычку видимо нужно эскейпить дважды или придумывать обходные пути.

Comment: Покажите, собственно, _JSON_.  Чую, у вас в нём проблема с экранированием.

Comment: @Ainar-G Добавил апдейтом

Comment: Я сейчас попробовал с двойными слешами - сработало. @KoVadim прав

Comment: @svstnv двойные слешы прямо везде? а это не ломает работоспособность самой регулярки? (сейчас попробую)

Comment: да, прям везде. Регулярка не ломается.
Вот, кстати, аналогичный вопрос на английском SO - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597238/escaping-regex-to-get-valid-json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение найдено благодаря комментаторам. Нужно экранировать экранирующие слеши, то есть вместо одного слеша ставить 2.

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/487702)

Comment: @CrazyElf идея таких ответов в том, чтобы вопрос не висел как открытый, будучи на самом деле решённым.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]. ответ почти нормальный. не хватает описания — где и почему «использовать двойные слэши»